# Get list of Hotels and room images from Expedia

Tags: asp.net, api

Using Asp.Net I want to get hotels and all corresponding properties such as hotel and room images from Expedia.

It gives all properties expect the images. I want to get hotel and room images with hotel list service. What should I do to achieve this?this is my request

```
var serviceClient = new HotelServicesClient("ExpediaServicePort");

            var serviceRequest = new HotelListRequest();
            serviceRequest.apiKey = _apiKey;
            serviceRequest.locale = _culture == "tr" ? LocaleType.tr_TR : LocaleType.en_US;
            serviceRequest.localeSpecified = true;
            serviceRequest.currencyCode = _culture == "tr" ? "TRY" : "EUR";
            serviceRequest.supplierType = "E";
            serviceRequest.searchRadius = 100;
            serviceRequest.searchRadiusSpecified = true;
            serviceRequest.searchRadiusUnit = SearchRadiusUnitType.KM;
            serviceRequest.searchRadiusUnitSpecified = true;
            serviceRequest.arrivalDate = hotelListRequest.ArrivalAt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            serviceRequest.departureDate = hotelListRequest.DepartureAt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            serviceRequest.RoomGroup = new[] { new Room { numberOfAdults = hotelListRequest.AdultCount, numberOfChildren = hotelListRequest.ChildCount } };
            serviceRequest.sort = SortType.PRICE;
            serviceRequest.sortSpecified = true;
            serviceRequest.numberOfResults = 50;
            serviceRequest.numberOfResultsSpecified = true;

            if (hotelListRequest.Latitude.HasValue && hotelListRequest.Longitude.HasValue)
            {
                serviceRequest.latitude = (float)hotelListRequest.Latitude.Value;
                serviceRequest.latitudeSpecified = true;
                serviceRequest.longitude = (float)hotelListRequest.Longitude.Value;
                serviceRequest.longitudeSpecified = true;
            }
            else
            {
                serviceRequest.destinationString = hotelListRequest.City;
            }

            var hotelListResponse = new Entity.HotelList.HotelListResponse();

            var response = serviceClient.getList(serviceRequest);

            if (response.EanWsError != null)
                throw new Exception(response.EanWsError.verboseMessage);

            hotelListResponse.CacheKey = response.cacheKey;
            hotelListResponse.CacheLocation = response.cacheLocation;
            hotelListResponse.HasMore = response.moreResultsAvailable;

            if (true)
            {
                foreach (var serviceHotel in response.HotelList.HotelSummary)
                {
                    var hotel =

                        new Entity.Hotel
                            {
                                RefID = serviceHotel.hotelId,
                                Url = hotelUrl(serviceHotel.hotelId, _htmlDecodeFunc(serviceHotel.name)),  .......
```

Comment: Does their API definitely support returning images? Can you give us a link to the documentation about images?

Comment: yes...i am looking their document ...i try something but not succed yet .....here is sentence from their document  "Example REST Hotel Room Availability Request with Property Images
Options=HOTEL_IMAGES..."   http://developer.ean.com/docs/room_avail/examples/REST_Room_Options

Answer (score 4):

The LIST api does not provide hotel images, only a thumbnail.
There are three places to get images, INFO (hotel images), ROOMIMAGES, and AVAIL (room images).

With the thumbnail provided from LIST (or any api), you can also get various formats by replacing the final '_b.' with '_l.' (landscape),'_s.' (small), or ....  Full replace values are listed here:
http://developer.ean.com/database_catalogs/relational/Image_Data
https://support.ean.com/entries/21965722-Additional-Image-Sizes-Available

Remember, you are limited to 40 requests/second on production so getting all images for the results of a LIST would eat that up quickly.  If you are using local versions of their DB files, you can get all the images from a LIST without pinging their API.  The first link above has the download location for that file and just requires some local (no)SQL integration.